# Words for shopping for medicine for athlete's foot in mainland China?

Tags: word-choice, word-requests

In my travels I sometimes get athlete's foot and my medicine for it is now running out while I'm in Guangzhou.

I see there are several Chinese terms for this condition. It's always difficult to know which is regional or old fashioned or too technical or has the wrong connotation.

Would I be OK using the wording "香港脚药"?

It's an attempt to say "athlete's foot medicine". But there might even be a more specific general term for such medicine or even some brand name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's usually called as [脚气](http://baike.baidu.com/view/36527.htm?fromtitle=%E8%84%9A%E6%B0%94&fromid=251021&type=syn) in spoken language, so you can say:

> 有治脚气的药吗？

AFAIK, `达克宁` is a famous brand of `脚气霜`, but I'm not sure whether it suits your case or not. So it's better to make a research before using it.

Answer (score 3):

請問，有沒有治香港腳的藥？would sound OK in Taiwan